# Understanding the Choleski factorization.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

I'm trying to understand the Choleski decomposition of a symmetric positive definite matrix A, given by $$A = CC^T,$$ where $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a lower triangular matrix. The argument made for the Choleski decomposition is that it only requires the calculation of one lower triangular matrix and thus results in less computational costs compared to the LU decomposition. To calculate the entries of $C$ my book gives the following formulas:

$$\text{For } k = 1\to n,\,\,C(k,k) = \sqrt{A(k,k) - \sum\limits_{j =1}^{k-1} C(k,j)^2},$$
$$\text{For }i = k+1\to n,\,\,C(i,k) = \bigg(A(i,k) - \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}C(i,j)C(k,j)\bigg)$$  where $C(k,k)$ is the element in the k-th row and k-th column of $C$. I have tried to understand these formulas by using an example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). The formulas are correct but it seems to me that they require you to already know $C$ while calculating $C$..

**Question:**

- How are you supposed to calculate $C(k,k)$ by using other elements of $C$ that you don't already know? The only reason I can think of is that you do already know some of $C$, because $C = LD$, where $D = diag(U)$ in the LU decomposition. However, don't you lose your computational advantage if you have to use parts of $L$ and $U$ to calculate $C$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "other elements of CC that you don't already know? " - [one section of the wikipedia page you link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky–Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky–Crout_algorithms) points out that "we can compute the $(i, j)$ entry if we know the entries to the left and above", and indicates how to continue

Comment: @AakashM could you be a bit more specific?